# "Back Navigation Caching disabled" error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, caching

I have page which contains a menu. If I select a menu say "changeWard" it opens up a modal dialog. If cancel button on modal dialog is clicked it calls the following java script method.

`function openChangeWardDialog() {

```
// returns:     0 if menu repainting is needed
//              -1 if menu repainting is not needed
var dialogFeatures = "dialogWidth:715px;dialogHeight:190px;center:yes;status:no;scroll:no;help:no";
var result = window.parent.doShowModalDialog("changeWardInit.do", "dialog", dialogFeatures);
if (typeof(result) != "string") {
    reportError("Unexpected result (" + typeof(buttonTagDlgRetVal) + "): '" + buttonTagDlgRetVal + "'");
} else {
    switch (result.toUpperCase()) {
    case "CANCEL":  // Cancel - do nothing
        event.returnValue = false;  // prevent follow 'href'
        window.parent.frames['content'].document.restoreFocus();
        return 0;                  // stay on the same item, redraw menu not needed`
```

I got the error below:
"The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337".

When this cancel button is clicked it takes me back to login page while it is supposed to take me to homepage which is defined as 'content' frame.
How can I disable this "back navigation caching" in IE 11. Because the issue is surfacing only on the IE 11. and other versions of IE it is working fine.

Comment: Hi everyone: Good News is that this is working now. I have added the code `window.onbeforeunload=null;`
just before the `return 0;` in the code snipped above.

Hope this also helps you.